# HTML5 call aspx but return error "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

i am fresh on html5 and i have try to use html5 javascript to call aspx but it always return error "undefined". code is like below. please help

```
<script>

    function sendrequest(e)
    {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "192.168.0.178/DealerWebRequest/GetAllDealerDetails.aspx",


            data:"{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                    alert("sdf");

                },
            error:function (r) {
                    alert(r.message);
                   // alert(JSON.stringify(data1));

                }
    });

    };

</script>
```

anyone can help tell me which part got problem. thanks

Comment: 'url' should contain the scheme (http:// or https://, e.g.).  Also, your data type will have to match up.  Are you really getting json back from a static page?

Comment: You are not sending any data to the aspx, which may be set to return nothing, or 403 forbidden, if it does not receive any data, both of which will result in an error

Comment: First try with simplest example.. i.e your file containing this script should be at same path (same host, same directory). 
and be simplest like

`$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetAllDealerDetails.aspx",

            success: function () {
                    alert("sdf");
                },
            error:function () {
                    alert('error');                   
                });` if you succeed then do your complete job

Comment: First you should check whether it's requesting the correct path. Press F12 in your browser, click "Network" tab and capture network traffic to see the requested url.